# Redirecting API requests in Django Rest Framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

I have a two-layer backend architecture:

- a "front" server, which serves web clients. This server's codebase is shared with a 3rd party developer
- a "back" server, which holds top-secret-proprietary-kick-ass-algorithms, and has a single endpoint to do its calculation

When a client sends a request to a specific endpoint in the "front" server, the server should pass the request to the "back" server. The back server then crunches some numbers, and returns the result.

One way of achieving it is to use the [requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/) library. A simpler way would be to have the "front" server simply redirect the request to the "back" server. I'm using DRF throughout both servers.

Is redirecting an ajax request possible using DRF?

Comment: Try to create a file utils.py to the functions you need in your "back" app and to import in your "front" server view `from back_server.utils import your_function`.

Comment: @MatheusVeleci - can't do that - the function's source cannot be shared between the servers

Comment: But given an API request from the "front" server,  do you want to return data from "back" server? Or just redirect to "back" url?

Comment: @MatheusVeleci - the "back" server returns data as an ajax response. So I can either: i) use the front-end as a middleman ii) redirect requests fron the "front" to "back" for that specific endpoint.

Comment: As I understand that you are using microservices architecture, two different and independent services, so why you do not use the request library, as you are leading with two distinct urls?

Comment: Why you think that using requests is a "harder" way? Just write simple proxy view based on DRF and requests and proxy your requests to your back server. So it will be seamless for your end users and pretty secure. Also you will be able to manage API versioning and provide compatibility layer between front and back servers in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't even need the DRF to add a redirection to urlconf. All you need to redirect is a simple rule:

```
urlconf = [
    url("^secret-computation/$",
        RedirectView.as_view(url=settings.BACKEND_SECRET_COMPUTATION_URL))),
    url("^", include(your_drf_router.urls)),
]
```

Of course, you may extend this to a proper DRF view, register it with the DRF's router (instead of directly adding `url` to `urlconf`), etc etc - but there isn't much sense in doing so to just return a redirect response.

However, the code above would only work for GET requests. You may subclass `HttpResponseRedirect` to return HTTP 307 (replacing `RedirectView` with your own simple view class or function), and depending on your clients, things may or may not work. If your clients are web browsers and those may include IE9 (or worse) then 307 won't help.

So, unless your clients are known to be all well-behaving (and on non-hostile networks without any weird way-too-smart proxies - you'll never believe what kinds of insanity those may do to HTTP requests), I'd suggest to actually proxy the request.

Proxying can be done either in Django - write a `GenericViewSet` subclass that uses `requests` library - or by using something in front of it, e.g. nginx or Caddy (or any other HTTP server/load balancer that you know best).

For production purposes, as you probably have a fronting webserver, I suggest to use that. This would save implementation time and also a little bit of server resources, as your "front" Django project won't even have to handle the request and keep the worker busy as it waits for the response.

For development purposes, your options may vary. If you use bare `runserver` then a proxy view may be your best option. If you use e.g. Docker, you may just throw in an HTTP server container in front of your Django container.

For example, I currently have a two-project setup (legacy Django 1.6 project and newer Django 1.11 project, sharing the same database) and a [Caddy server](https://caddyserver.com/) in front of those, routing on per-URL basis. With a simple 9-line Caddyfile things just work:

```
:80
tls off
log / stdout "{common}"
proxy /foo project1:8000 {
    transparent
}
proxy / project2:8000 {
    transparent
}
```

(This is a development-mode config.) If you can have something similar, then, I guess, that would be the simplest option.